# Entity Framework - Optimistic Concurrency Issue

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, entity

I have a windows service that runs every 10 seconds ... each time it runs, it takes some test data, modifies it and persists it to the database using the EntityFramework. However, on every second run, when I try to persist the change I get the following Optimistic Concurrency Exception:-

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries

I know for a fact that there is nothing else writing to that DB but my service which updates records every 10 seconds. What could be causing the concurrency exception here ?

I think a related entity somewhere in the object graph was getting modified prior to the second save operation. 
All i am doing really is instantiating a new object context, and calling a save operation on some records i had retrieved using the same context. 
The following code worked ---

```
var ctx = new blahEntities();
var profile = ctx.ProfileSet.Where(pr=>pr.FirstName.Contains("a")).FirstOrDefault();
profile.Address = "modified";
ctx.SaveChanges();
ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,profile);
```

Comment: I assume you are calling `SubmitChanges()`. You might try creating a fresh copy of your `ObjectContext` each time.

Comment: Yes I call "SaveChanges" which is the EF equivalent of "SubmitChanges". When you say "Create a fresh copy of your ObjectContext do you mean each time the service enters the loop, you want a new objectcontext to be passed ? Right now, the object context is created once when the service starts and it is reused to perform DB operations. Is there a way to refresh the existing context ?

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate how you are modifying your entities, because i have seen this happen as a result of attaching/detached entities.

Comment: So I resolved the issue by forcing a Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity) after a successful save. I read that to be  a recommended step here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "unexpected number of rows (0)" indicates that more than likely you don't have an ID field correctly mapped or defined in your entity model, or you are modifying a detached entity and attempting to save it and it doesn't have key information.

Run SQL Server profiler, or Entity Framework Profiler, and see what is going on in the background.

Comment: Just had the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Once had this same issue and spent hours tracking it down to a malfunctioning update trigger.  If you have any triggers on the table that's being updated, make sure they're working correctly.  I work in an Oracle environment, fwiw.