# Entity Framework Concurrency Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to add a new record to the entity framework and I'm getting this error when adding the record:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

This is the code I have (note: I'm getting the same exception in both the try/catch block):

```
try
                    {
                        AppBLL.Context.Schools.AddObject(school);
                        AppBLL.Context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException ex)
                    {

                        AppBLL.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, AppBLL.Context.Schools);       
                        AppBLL.Context.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the school object look like?

Comment: @McBoman what exactly about the school object you want to know..the structure or...? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Optimistic Concurrency Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901033/entity-framework-optimistic-concurrency-issue)

Comment: More if all the needed data is filled out.

Comment: @McBoman fyi, when I'm executing the same query which is generated from EF and is visible in the Sql Profiler via SSMS I'm getting no errors. Is that helping you? Thanks